# Angular Material card shadow colour

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there any way to change the colour of the shadow which is dark under the card?

If any solution please let me know or any other workaround is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: you can override the component style by setting the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and the setting     `box-shadow: 1px 2px 10px 0 #ff0000 !important;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding the following to your CSS will change the `box-shadow` for the `mat-card`

```
.mat-card:not([class*=mat-elevation-z]) {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,1), 
                0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1), 
                0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

If you are using an elevation, of course this CSS will need to be modified a bit.

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yxb2ow?embed=1&file=app/card-overview-example.css

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the latest [angular material elevation](https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation#mixins)

You can do something like this in style.sass

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

.my-class-with-custom-shadow {
  // Adds a shadow for elevation level 2 with color #e91e63 and 80% of the default opacity:
  @include mat-elevation(2, #e91e63, 0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.mat-card {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #9b9b9b,
        0 1px 1px 0 #9b9b9b,
        0 1px 3px 0 #9b9b9b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your global style.scss or style.css (Whichever css format you're using)
you can use the following code.

**Please note that, this is for Angular Material CDK 16**

```css
.mat-mdc-card {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px #00000026 !important;
    border-radius: 1em !important;
}
```